# Getting the value from usercontrol in javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this following scenario. I have a usercontrol in my page which has a radio button. This control is placed in a page, on click of a button in the page I need to know if the radio button is selected. This is a client event click event of the button as I have to show a confirmation message box i.e. if user clicks yes only then I have to do the remaining operation. Can you guide me what would be the best way to find if the radio button in the userControl is selected.

Thanks

Comment: `var radioButtonObject = document.getElementById('radio_id'); if (radioButtonObject.checked) { /* do this */} else { /* do that*/ }`

Comment: @Mathletics i have tried something like fallowing on server on click of radiobutton and use the IsYes value in js file ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "IsYes",
                "var IsYes = true;", true);

Answer (score 1):

If the page needs to know, add a public property to the UC:

```
public bool IsRadioSelected { get { return Radio.Checked; } }
```

You can also have the RadioButton postback on changing the check by setting the AutoPostBack property to true.

EDIT: For client script, you could also add a public property to the RadioButton:

```
public string RadioClientID { get { return Radio.ClientID; } }
```

Then in javascript, you can do:

```
var radioButtonObject = document.getElementById('<%= RadioClientID %>'); 
if (radioButtonObject.checked) { /* do this */} else { /* do that*/ }
```

The problem is the ID of the radio button in client script looks like "ct100_Body_somecontainer_RadioID" and can't be easily directly referenced.  The approach above is safer.

Comment: i have a public property in the control, problem for me is getting the value in javascript, i am not able to get the control and property in script.